# Existence of Aronszajn tree

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, trees, infinitary-combinatorics

There are theories that prove the existence and non-existence of Souslin trees [exist if $V=L$, don't exist if $\mathsf{MA}(\aleph_1)$] and Kurepa trees [exist if $V=L$, don't exist by Lévy collapsing a strongly inaccessible cardinal to $\aleph_2$].

The existence of Aronszajn trees is provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Is there a theory (stronger than $\mathsf{ZF}$) that refutes the existence of Aronszajn trees?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.

If you collapse a weakly compact to $\omega_1$, then the Solovay model you get is one where there are no Aronszajn trees on $\omega_1$. The same would work if you collapse a Mahlo, you'd get that there are no special Aronszajn trees.

This is easy to see in the following argument: If $A$ is a set of ordinals in the Solovay model, then it is definable from a real. Namely, it was introduced by a bounded collapse. But if $T$ is a tree on $\omega_1$, it can be coded by a set of ordinals, and thus was added by a bounded collapse. In the model given by only forcing with that bounded part, the weakly compact we collapse is still weakly compact, so $T$ has a branch there, and therefore in the Solovay model.

---

Of course, one has to be careful as to what *is* an Aronszajn tree in this context. Does it have to be well-ordered? Maybe just its initial segments need to be well-ordered? Maybe you want to talk about other cardinals, other than $\omega_1$ itself, in which case the answer is also positive:

> *Apter, Arthur W.*, [**A remark on the tree property in a choiceless context**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00153-011-0233-z), Arch. Math. Logic 50, No. 5-6, 585-590 (2011). [ZBL1221.03049](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1221.03049).

Comment: I have never even considered a tree that is not well-ordered... How should I think of one?

Comment: Well, you can consider a family of $\omega_1$ pairs such that no uncountable subfamily admits a choice function. Then the tree of partial choice functions is, potentially, a tree of height $\omega_1$ and without branches. If one is careful, it is *conceivable* that one can define an Aronszajn tree out of it (and in other cases, one can find more direct arguments as to how to construct those, e.g. if you have a homogeneous Aronszajn tree, you can "replicate it" as a non-well-orderable tree, such that any proper initial segment of the tree is in fact countable).